# enable router calls on el-submenus in Element-UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to set up a Navbar in Element-UI with a nested submenu.  In additions to opening the submenu, I want the router to go to the index attribute of the submenu.  This doesn't happen; clicking on a submenu doesn't activate the router - it only works for `el-menu-item` and not `el-submenu`, as far as I can tell.

Here's my code:

```
<el-submenu index="2">
    <template slot="title"><feather type="edit"></feather></template>
    <el-submenu :index="subject.label" v-for="subject in subjects">
    <template @click="setSubject(subject.label)" slot="title">{{ subject.label }}</template>
    <el-submenu :index="spec.label" v-for="spec in subject.children">
        <template slot="title">{{ spec.label }}</template>
        <el-menu-item :index="prac.label" v-for="prac in spec.children">{{ prac.label }}</el-menu-item>
    </el-submenu>
    </el-submenu>       
</el-menu-item>
```

I tried adding a click event to `<el-submenu :index="subject.label" v-for="subject in subjects">`'s template called `setSubject`.  It fails to execute when clicked.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox or codepen with minimal code?